# many-to-many mysql search looking for team that im not in

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm struggling with this MySql query.

---

I have 3 tables.

```
member
idMember memberEmail
1        joe@dalton.com
2        jack@dalton.com
3        lucky@luke.com

team
idTeam teamName
1      King
2      Lion
3      Cat

teamMember
idMember idTeam
1        1
2        1
3        2
3        3
```

I need a query that return the team the idMember is not registered.
eg: idMember 1 , not regestered in Team 2 and 3.

any idea?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM [team] T
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM teamMember TM WHERE idMember = [1] AND T.idTeam = TM.idTeam )
```

Replace [team] with the name of the second table (team id, name) and [1] with the id member you want to search for.

Comment: Thanks Stephanie, but that query returns an empty table.

Comment: Oops ! I forgot to add a condition for the teams to be equivalent.  I also added in table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking fro a particular `idmember`:

```
select t.idTeam
from team t
where not exists (select 1
                  from teamMember tm
                  where tm.teamId = t.teamId and tm.memberId = 1
                 );
```

This is called a *correlated subquery*.  You can do something similar with `not in`:

```
select t.idTeam
from team t
where t.idTeam not in (select tm.idTeam
                       from teamMember tm
                       where tm.memberId = 1
                      );
```

However, `not exists` is preferable because of the way that `not in` handles `null` values in the subquery.

Comment: @PatriceCarle . . . Stephanie's answer was not correct when I answered the question.

Comment: I'm very sorry for that, but Im realy greatfull of your answer to. thanks for the fast reply.